# Find value anywhere in the arrays, output content

Tags: php

I have the array `$conversion[$cohort_check]` which is outputting the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 62056
            [order_date] => 21-01
            [total] => 5.5
            [cumulative] => 0
            [order_type] => one_time
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 52937
            [order_date] => 21-02
            [total] => 5.5
            [cumulative] => 0
            [order_type] => one_time
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 45849
            [order_date] => 21-03
            [total] => 7.89
            [cumulative] => 0
            [order_type] => parent
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 228
            [order_date] => 21-10
            [total] => 5.23
            [cumulative] => 0
            [order_type] => parent
        )

)
```

How can I check if the value of `order_type` is `parent` exists anywhere within it?

I tried the following but don't think I'm quite hitting the right place.

```
if(in_array("parent", $conversion[$cohort_check])){
    echo "subscribed!";
}
```

Is it then possible to grab the value of `order_date` for the first parent order it gets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need to loop over the array. PHP has the https://www.php.net/array_search, which does exactly what you need:

If you want just one result:

```
array_search('parent', array_column($array, 'order_type'));
```

For multiple results

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($array, 'order_type'), 'parent');
```

Comment: Is it possible to grab the `order_date` from the first parent array it then finds?

Comment: @Rob Using the first array_search will return the key of the first occurence containing 'parent'. From there since you have the key you can retrieve the `order_date` field by key

Comment: @slashroot Ah ok that makes sense. I've used `$conversion[$cohort_check][$parent_check]['order_date']` to grab it

Comment: That sounds correct, as long as `$parent_check` is the key result of your `array_search`

Answer (score 0):

This will loop the array and **echo** the `order_id` that has `order_type` as `parent` (Subscribed).

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'order_id' => 1589,
        'order_type' => 'one_time'
    ),
    array(
        'order_id' => 1579,
        'order_type' => 'parent'
    ),
    array(
        'order_id' => 1289,
        'order_type' => 'one_time'
    ),
    array(
        'order_id' => 2589,
        'order_type' => 'parent'
    ),
    array(
        'order_id' => 1584,
        'order_type' => 'one_time'
    ),
    array(
        'order_id' => 8589,
        'order_type' => 'one_time'
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value['order_type'] === 'parent') {
        echo 'Order: ' . $value['order_id'] . ': Subscribed' . '<br>';
    }
}
// Output
Order: 1579: Subscribed
Order: 2589: Subscribed
```

**EDIT:**

There is another answer with `array_keys(array_column($array, 'order_type'), 'parent')` this indeed works fine but you're still going to have to then process that array to get some meaningful information like the `order_id`. Assuming that is ultimately what you're wanting (To see what order is subscribed).

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = array(
    array(

        'order_id' => '62056',
        'order_date' => '21-01',
        'total' => '5.5',
        'cumulative' => '0',
        'order_type' => 'one_time'
    ),
    array(

        'order_id' => '62056',
        'order_date' => '21-01',
        'total' => '5.5',
        'cumulative' => '0',
        'order_type' => 'one_time'
    ),
    array(

        'order_id' => '52937',
        'order_date' => '21-02',
        'total' => '5.5',
        'cumulative' => '0',
        'order_type' => 'parent'
    ),
);
```

simply use foreach loop and then apply your condition on particular key

```
foreach ($x as $key => $xx) {
    if($xx["order_type"] == "parent" ){
        echo "Subscribed";
    }
}
```